# PHP Date Month Not Calculating Properly

Tags: php, arrays, date, strtotime

```
$months = array();
$first = strtotime("first day this month");
for ( $i = 1; $i <= 6; $i++ ) {
    array_push($months, date('F', strtotime("-$i month", $first)));
}
var_dump($months);
```

This code is not working properly when run today (in march)

Output:

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "March"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "January"
  [2]=>
  string(8) "December"
  [3]=>
  string(8) "November"
  [4]=>
  string(7) "October"
  [5]=>
  string(9) "September"
}
```

Where is February?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP DateTime::modify adding and subtracting months](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602405/php-datetimemodify-adding-and-subtracting-months)

Comment: I'm not using DateTime nor am I using the last day of the month.

Comment: That answer explains everything in your question

Comment: I don't want to use DateTime :)

Comment: Doesn't matter. That explains *why* it happens. Now that you know why it happens you know *how* to work around it. And why don't you want to use `DateTime()`? I can't think of a valid reason not to.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code into this to see what actually happens:

```
$months = array();
$first = strtotime("first day this month");
echo date('d-F-Y', $first);
for ( $i = 1; $i <= 6; $i++ ) {
    array_push($months, date('d-F-Y', strtotime("-$i month", $first)));
}
var_dump($months);
```

You will see that your `$first` date is not right. It is set at `29-March-2014`. Why is February not there? Because it only has 28 days :)

Solution is: `$first = strtotime("first day of this month");` which outputs `01-March-2014`.