# DateTime addition of interval gives wrong ans

Tags: php, datetime, strtotime

2While trying to get the next month by adding the `+1 month` in strtotime function as well DateTime class, its not giving right answer when start date time is 31 January 2011.

```
<?php

$StartDateline = new DateTime("31 January 2011");

echo date('Y-m-d', $StartDateline->getTimestamp());
echo "<br>";
$EndDateline = $StartDateline->add(new DateInterval("P1M"));//strtotime("+1 month", $startDateline);

echo date('Y-m-d', $EndDateline->getTimestamp());

echo "<br>";

?>
```

Output is :

```
2011-01-31
2011-03-03
```

Expected result should be following or how should I get the following out put :

```
2011-01-31
2011-02-28
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean 2011-02-28?

Comment: refer http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: Why on earth would you expect  1 month to add 2 months to your date?

Comment: your expected result is more than 25 days beyond what it should be

Comment: Mistakenly I have written `2011-03-28` it should be `2011-02-28`. Thanks @YUNOWORK

Comment: @krishna I've updated my answer, please review and accpet if it helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
<?php
    $StartDateline = new DateTime("31 January 2011");
    echo date('Y-m-d', $StartDateline->getTimestamp());
    echo "<br>";

    $test = $StartDateline->modify('last day of next month');
    echo date('Y-m-d', $test->getTimestamp());
    echo "<br>";
?>
```

result:

```
2011-01-31
2011-02-28
```

Here's a similar [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3602405/2460773) that exaplains why your way doesn't give the wanted output.

PHP docs on [DateTime::modify](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php) method

***edit:***
I understand now that you don't need the last day of next month, but the same day of next month.
I found this code working:

```
function addMonthsToTime($numMonths = 1, $timeStamp = null){
    $timeStamp === null and $timeStamp = time();//Default to the present
    $newMonthNumDays =  date('d',strtotime('last day of '.$numMonths.' months', $timeStamp));//Number of days in the new month
    $currentDayOfMonth = date('d',$timeStamp);

    if($currentDayOfMonth > $newMonthNumDays){
      $newTimeStamp = strtotime('-'.($currentDayOfMonth - $newMonthNumDays).' days '.$numMonths.' months', $timeStamp);
    } else {
    $newTimeStamp = strtotime($numMonths.' months', $timeStamp);
    }

    return $newTimeStamp;
}

$timestamp = strtotime('2011-01-01');
echo date('m/d/Y', addMonthsToTime(1, $timestamp));
//02/01/2011

$timestamp = strtotime('2011-01-31');
echo date('m/d/Y', addMonthsToTime(1, $timestamp));
//02/28/2011
```

taken from [this](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php#113140) comment section on PHP's [Relative Formats](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php) doc page.

Comment: I want in general, Like 30 or 31 Jan 2011 goes to 28 Feb 2011, 1 Jan 2011 should goes to 1 Feb 2011

Comment: If my answer is correct consider accepting it.If your question changed, please edit your question above.

Comment: @NitsanBaleli: wyh would you even mix `date()` function and `DateTime` object?

Answer (score 0):

instead of specifying `month` specify `date`.

```
new DateInterval("P#D")// # no. of days.
```

or you can use `modify`.see here:http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php

Answer (score 0):

**The current behavior of PHP DateTime is not wrong.  What's really happening is**

- +1 month increases the month number (originally 1) by one. This makes the date 2011-03-03.
- The second month (February) only has 28 days in 2011, so PHP
  auto-corrects this by just continuing to count days from February
  1st. You then end up at March 3rd. January 31 + 31 days (1 month) = March 3 ( since there are only 28 days in february)

  See [@shamittomar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602405/php-datetimemodify-adding-and-subtracting-months)

**To get the expected answer you should use the number of days**

- That's why in the [***PHP Manual DateTime***](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) it says beware when adding months.

So just replace `P1M` with `P28D` to get desired result

```
$EndDateline = $StartDateline->add(new DateInterval("P28D"));
```

[**See DEMO**](https://eval.in/194003)

Comment: Since I want to increase a month in general, I don't know the date is 31 Jan or 30 Jan. or 1 Jan 2011. I just want to increase one month e.g : * 1 Jan 2011 should goes to 1 Feb 2011, * 30 or 31 Jan 2011 both should goes 28 Feb 2011 and so on. I want it is general.

Comment: @krishna you can do conditional statements with that one

Comment: Okay, Is it not possible through `Datetime` methods or `strtotime` function ??

Comment: @krishna You can use P1M  but there's a catch when february comes. That's why it is up to you to consider that and in the manual http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php example three it says Beware when adding months. So use conditional statements to check the month. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602405/php-datetimemodify-adding-and-subtracting-months or study $d->modify( 'first day of next month' )

Answer (score 0):

[John Robertson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25863454/67332) already explained why you get the result you get. The output is correct, because when you add +1 month to `31.1.` it will become `31.2.` which is `3 days` more than `28.2.`, so correct results is `3.3.`.

For your needs, you will need a custom script, what will handle carry-over-day your way, for example:

```php
$start = new DateTime('31 January 2011');

$new   = clone $start;
$new->modify('first day of next month'); 
$newDay = ($start->format('j') > $new->format('t') ? $new->format('t') : $start->format('j')) - 1;
$new->modify("+{$newDay} days");

echo $start->format('Y-m-d'), " > ", $new->format('Y-m-d');
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/194282)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for your response, it really help to out from the problem.