# Adding 2 months in PHP

Tags: php, date

I've seen previous problems about adding two months to an existing date, however the existing answers do not help me much as I am getting different results than what I want. I have set up a date as follows:

```
$date = "2014-12-31";
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("$date +2 month"));
```

After I've added 2 months, I print it:

```
echo $date;
```

My result:

> 2015-03-03

but this is not right to me because this is a full month beyond what I actually want:

> 2015-02-28

How can I do this?

Comment: thanks to edit ketan.

Comment: I believe this is the issue you are running into: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602405/php-datetimemodify-adding-and-subtracting-months?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `DateTime` class and modify method argument like `last day of second month`

```
$date = new DateTime('2014-12-31');
$date->modify('last day of second month');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Edit::

`modify` can have multiple possible arguments

> last day of 2 month
>
> last day of +2 month

Comment: Wouldn't second month be interpreted as February?

Comment: its based on the date. php DateTime class will automatically convert it.

Answer (score 9):

I would use PHP's DateTime class.

```
$date = new DateTime('2014-12-31');
$date->modify('+2 month');
$date->format('Y-m-d');
echo $date;
```

It also depends on what you are expecting by 2 months, this can vary based on how many days in the month there are. Are you going by 30 days, 31 days, last day of month, first day of month?...etc.

Maybe you are looking for this,

```
$date = new DateTime('2014-12-31');
$date->modify('last day of +2 month');
$date->format('Y-m-d');
echo $date;
```

This may also help you. [Relative Formats](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php)

Comment: i tried this code but.
Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string in /home/hosting_users/cashq/www/test/strtotime.php on line 14

this error code to fix how to do that?

Comment: Seems that you are doing something different than what I posted.

Comment: DateTime is an object, but the format method will return a string which you can echo. E.g., you can use the following: `echo $date->format('Y-m-d');`

Comment: thanks to @David and @EternalHour 
datetime class used for Success. but this result same
`$date = new DateTime('2014-12-31');
$date->modify('+2 month');
//$date->format('Y-m-d');
echo "<br>";
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');`

**2015-03-03**

what's wrong???

Comment: @taebu look at my comment under your question.