# PHP February date: "2015-01-31" +1 month: "2015-03-30". How to fix?

Tags: php, date, datetime

If I use this code I get strange results:

```
$datetime = new DateTime('2015-01-31');
$datetime->modify('+1 month');
echo $datetime->format('Y-m-t') . "<br>";
$datetime->modify('+1 month');
echo $datetime->format('Y-m-t') . "<br>";
$datetime->modify('+1 month');
echo $datetime->format('Y-m-t') . "<br>";
```

I get this:

```
2015-03-31
2015-04-30
2015-05-31
```

And not `2015-02-28`.

How to fix?

Comment: @all: Is this a real bug ? This is clearly breaking usability and definitly breaking lots of applications.

Answer (score 4):

The way `DateTime` works, `+ 1 month` increases the month value by one, giving you `2015-02-31`. Since there are only 28 or 29 days in February, that will evaluate to the first few days of March. Then, as you know, asking for `Y-m-t` will give you the last day of March.

Since you're already using `t` to get the last day of the month, you could avoid this problem by *starting* with a date that falls at the beginning of a month instead:

```
$datetime = new DateTime('2015-01-01');
```

Reference: [PHP DateTime::modify adding and subtracting months](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602405/php-datetimemodify-adding-and-subtracting-months#answer-3602421)

Comment: This should be the accepted answear!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the last day of the next month, you can use:

```
$datetime->modify('last day of next month');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this function to add months to a datetime object

```
    /**
 * 
 * @param \DateTime $date DateTime object
 * @param int $monthToAdd Months to add at time
 */
function addMonth(\DateTime $date, $monthToAdd)
{
    $year = $date->format('Y');
    $month = $date->format('n');
    $day = $date->format('d');

    $year += floor($monthToAdd / 12);
    $monthToAdd = $monthToAdd % 12;
    $month += $monthToAdd;
    if ($month > 12) {
        $year ++;
        $month = $month % 12;
        if ($month === 0) {
            $month = 12;
        }
    }

    if (! checkdate($month, $day, $year)) {
        $newDate = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-n-j', $year . '-' . $month . '-1');
        $newDate->modify('last day of');
    } else {
        $newDate = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-n-d', $year . '-' . $month . '-' . $day);
    }
    $newDate->setTime($date->format('H'), $date->format('i'), $date->format('s'));

    return $newDate->format('Y-m-d');
}

echo addMonth(new \DateTime('2015-01-30'), 1); //2015-02-28
echo addMonth(new \DateTime('2015-01-30'), 2); //2015-03-30
echo addMonth(new \DateTime('2015-01-30'), 3); //2015-04-30
```

Answer (score -2):

Fix it like this.

```
$datetime = new DateTime('2015-01-31');
$datetime->modify('28 days');
echo $datetime->format('Y-m-t') . "<br>";
$datetime->modify('+1 month');
echo $datetime->format('Y-m-t') . "<br>";
$datetime->modify('+1 month');
echo $datetime->format('Y-m-t') . "<br>";
```

You will get

```
2015-02-28
2015-03-31
2015-04-30
```

Comment: You are genius, really!! GENIUS!!! GENIUS!!!

Comment: Not really.. this doesn't work in general. Only if you already know that you're dealing with January, and then, well, why use `DateTime` to get you to February at all? Much better to pick a simple solution that always works and always looks the same, as mopo posted.

Comment: I'm joking when i'm saying you are genius.