# twig date_diff month not working properly

Tags: symfony, twig

I try do date_diff last month, but have a problem if month have 31 day he say I'm to 01 at this month. And if do 2 month later give good result. But again every month who have 31 days give result to 01.

To be more clear i example you:

```
{{ "now" | date("Y-m-d") }} {# 2015-07-31 #}
{{ "now" | date_modify("-1 month") | date("Y-m-d") }} {# 2015-07-01 #}
{{ "now" | date_modify("-2 month") | date("Y-m-d") }} {# 2015-05-31 #}
{{ "now" | date_modify("-3 month") | date("Y-m-d") }} {# 2015-05-01 #}
```

Any1 have any ideea why ? Because any if modify month with even number you go at month start not to the end of previous month.

Comment: That seems bizarre - I assume that `\DateTime()` is being used under the hood. I tried the following in straight PHP (v 5.6) which replicates the issue: `$dt = new DateTime(); echo $dt->modify('-1 month')->format('Y-m-d');`. Going back two months yielded `2015-05-31`. Ah datetimes... Pretty interesting!

Comment: Hmm... check Example #2 in the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php) - it says "Beware when adding or subtracting months", but it does not say why...

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP DateTime::modify adding and subtracting months](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602405/php-datetimemodify-adding-and-subtracting-months)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602405/php-datetimemodify-adding-and-subtracting-months) it seems that when PHP modifies a `DateTime()` object with the string `'-1 month'` it simply decrements the month value, if I understand correctly.

So given your example, you start with today's date: `2015-07-31`.

PHP changes this to `2015-06-31`. However, there are only 30 days in June. So it increments this up to the next date that makes sense, which is... `2015-07-01`.

I tried replicating this with:

```
echo (new DateTime())->sub(new DateInterval('P1M'))->format('Y-m-d');
```

and:

```
$dt = new DateTime();
$dt->modify('-1 month');
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d');
```

and I got the exact same result in each case:

> 2015-07-01

So I guess it's just one of PHP's foibles. Pretty messy, a lot can happen in a day!