# Unable to understand behavior of the DateTime class in PHP

Tags: php, datetime

I am using LAMP in Kubuntu 14.04 with PHP 5.6.23.

When using [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) in follwing cases:

1.

```
print_r((new DateTime('2016-02-31'))->format('M/d/Y')); 
// Mar/02/2016 (no errors, why?)
```

2.

```
print_r((new DateTime('2016-02-32'))->format('M/d/Y')); 
// Error - DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string-
// (2016-02-32) at position 9 (2): Unexpected character
```

Why the first case give me no error, as there is no 31st date of February month?

*References supporting answer are requested*

Comment: have you ever seen a month with more than `31` days ?

Comment: The error comes because there are no months with more than 31 days. It works for February because it adds the extra days (2 or 3) and results in March. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602405/php-datetimemodify-adding-and-subtracting-months#answer-3602421

Comment: Because `32` is not a legal day of the month. The other case it will notice that there is no 31 of feb and will calculate the correct next day.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [php docs:](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php)

> It is possible to over- and underflow the dd and DD format. Day 0
>   means the last day of previous month, whereas overflows count into the
>   next month. This makes "2008-08-00" equivalent to "2008-07-31" and
>   "2008-06-31" equivalent to "2008-07-01" (June only has 30 days).
>
> Note that as of PHP 5.1.0 the day range is restricted to 0-31 as
>   indicated by the regular expression above. Thus "2008-06-32" is not a
>   valid date string, for instance.

This makes it pretty clear.

In the user notes `Mirek` also suggest to ***use*** `mktime` if you need:

> unlimited over/underflow for date calculations (for example 2015-01-40
>   to 2015-02-09)