# Adding 12 months to February 29

Tags: php

I want to add 12 months to my date. My start date is 02/29/2020 and I want to add 12 months to this.

**Code:**

```
$startdate = '02/29/2020';
date('m/d/Y', strtotime('+12 months', strtotime($startdate)));
```

**Output:**

```
03/01/2021
```

I used this code to add 12 months but the output is **03/01/2021**, when the real output should be **02/28/2020**.

Comment: in 2021 feb is of 28 days only. so it switch to march 3rd

Comment: @AnantSingh---AlivetoDie I know that 2021 is not a leap year but the real output should be 02/28/2020 right instead of 03/01/2021

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602405/php-datetimemodify-adding-and-subtracting-months

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look!

```
 function add_months($months, DateTime $dateObject) 
   {
        $next = new DateTime($dateObject->format('Y-m-d'));
        $next->modify('last day of +'.$months.' month');

        if($dateObject->format('d') > $next->format('d')) {
            return $dateObject->diff($next);
        } else {
            return new DateInterval('P'.$months.'M');
        }
    }

function getCalculatedDate($d1, $months)
{
    $date = new DateTime($d1);

    // call second function to add the months
    $newDate = $date->add(add_months($months, $date));

    //formats final date to m/d/Y form
    $dateReturned = $newDate->format('m/d/Y'); 

    return $dateReturned;
}
```

An example would be:-

```
$startDate = '02/29/2020';
$nMonths = 12; // choose how many months you want to add
$finalDate = getCalculatedDate($startDate, $nMonths); // output: 02/28/2021
```

This way you will get the output of `02/28/2021`

Answer (score 1):

using `DateTime` and `DateInterval` objects leads to `03/01/2021`

```
$date = new \DateTime('02/29/2020');
$date->add(new \DateInterval('P12M'));    
echo $date->format('m/d/Y');
```

for me `03/01/2021` is not always a bad answer

Comment: Getting value as `02/05/2023` can you recheck it, please

Comment: sorry d/m/Y instead of m/d/Y

Answer (score 1):

```
$startdate = '02/29/2020';
$date = date('m/d/Y', strtotime($startdate . '+365 days'));
```