# Adding minutes to date time not working properly

Tags: php, datetime, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am working on `Yii2`. In it I am trying to insert data into 3 different stages. i.e. I am using 3 queries one by one to insert different types of data. The data insertion is perfect but date-time is not. As I want to add data continuously so I have added a `for loop`. But the date-time it's inserting is always the same. See my code below

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 60; $i++) 
{
  $dt = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
 $model401->data_date_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+5 minutes', strtotime($dt)));
 $model402->data_date_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+10 minutes', strtotime($dt)));
 $model403->data_date_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+15 minutes', strtotime($dt)));
.
.
.
.
.
.
}
```

The date-time is saving in DB is same i.e.

`2020-04-25 11:11:57` first record date

`2020-04-25 11:16:57` second record date

`2020-04-25 11:21:57` third record date

`2020-04-25 11:11:57` fourth record date

`2020-04-25 11:16:57` fifth record  date

`2020-04-25 11:21:57` sixth record date

**Table View**

[image]

**Update 1**

```
for($i=0; $i<=60; $i++)
{
try {
            $cust_met_data = Yii::$app->db->createCommand(
            /** @lang text */ "SELECT m.`meter_id` , m.`msn` , 
                  m.`cust_id` , m.`device_id` FROM `mdc_meter_cust_rel` m ")->queryAll();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
        }

        $slave_id = $cust_met_data[0]['device_id'];
        $address = 0;
        $count = 14;
        $msn = $cust_met_data[0]['msn'];
        $cust_id = $cust_met_data[0]['cust_id'];

        // my base URL
        $api_url = 'https://localhost:44337/api/rtu/GetData/' . $slave_id . '/' . $address . '/' . $count;


        $curl = curl_init($api_url);

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1000);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);

        $json = json_decode($curl_response);

        if ($json->{0} == '06') {
            echo " line 1656 ";
            echo " An error occurs ";

            //return $this->redirect(['index']);
        } else {
            echo " line 1663 ";
            $vol_1 = $json->{0};
            $vol_2 = $json->{1};
            $vol_3 = $json->{2};
            $curr_1 = $json->{3};
            $curr_2 = $json->{4};
            $curr_3 = $json->{5};
            $kwh = $json->{6};

            $dt =  date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $currDt = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+5 minutes', strtotime($dt)));
            $volDt = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+10 minutes', strtotime($dt)));
            $kwhDt = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+15 minutes', strtotime($dt)));
            $typeCurr = "401";
            $typeVol = "402";
            $typeKwh = "403";

            /***** for current *****/
            echo " adding current values ";

            $model401 = new MdcmetersData();
           // $model401->load(Yii::$app->request->post());
            $model401->data_date_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+5 minutes', strtotime($dt)));
            $model401->device_id = $slave_id;
            $model401->msn = $msn;
            $model401->cust_id = $cust_id;
            $model401->voltage_p1 = "";
            $model401->voltage_p2 = "";
            $model401->voltage_p3 = "";
            $model401->current_p1 = $curr_1;
            $model401->current_p2 = $curr_2;
            $model401->current_p3 = $curr_3;
            $model401->kwh = "";
            $model401->d_type = "401";
            $model401->save();


            /***** for voltages *****/
            echo " adding voltages values ";


            $model402 = new MdcmetersData();
            //$model402->load(Yii::$app->request->post());
            $model402->data_date_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+10 minutes', strtotime($dt)));
            $model402->device_id = $slave_id;
            $model402->msn = $msn;
            $model402->cust_id = $cust_id;
            $model402->voltage_p1 = $vol_1;
            $model402->voltage_p2 = $vol_2;
            $model402->voltage_p3 = $vol_3;
            $model402->current_p1 = "";
            $model402->current_p2 = "";
            $model402->current_p3 = "";
            $model402->kwh = "";
            $model402->d_type = "402";
            $model402->save();


            /***** for kwh *****/
            echo " adding kwh values ";

            $model403 = new MdcmetersData();
           // $model403->load(Yii::$app->request->post());
            $model403->data_date_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+15 minutes', strtotime($dt)));
            $model403->device_id = $slave_id;
            $model403->msn = $msn;
            $model403->cust_id = $cust_id;
            $model403->voltage_p1 = "";
            $model403->voltage_p2 = "";
            $model403->voltage_p3 = "";
            $model403->current_p1 = "";
            $model403->current_p2 = "";
            $model403->current_p3 = "";
            $model403->kwh = $kwh;
            $model403->d_type = "403";
            $model403->save();


        }

    }
    }
```

You can see that first to 3rd and fourth to sixth date-time are the same. How can I set the date-time accurately?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You don't show how you set the fourth onwards, also check you are using the right variable names and not just copied and pasted.

Comment: @NigelRen I am doing the same for all date-time. The variables are ok. But I think issue is with the loop. If I remove the loop then the date-time is perfectly alright

Comment: Looking to the actual coe you have post you just repeat the same code 60 times ...  your code seems not related  to the loop variables $i.. is not clear what happen in the loop

Comment: @scaisEdge every time the loop starts it assigning the same date-time. That's what happening

Comment: Your code  . is not enough  .. show me the action where there is the loop e and also the part where you manage/save the model/data  to db.

Comment: @scaisEdge it's a console program. I am trying to run a job. Let me add

Comment: @scaisEdge I have updated my question kindly see it

Comment: In your code  ..  there is not  loop and overall there is not the model create ..   how do you manage this  ..  are you sure you are not saving always the same 3 models????

Comment: @scaisEdge added the loop and yes I am saving the same model

Comment: set timezone in config `'timeZone' => 'Asia/Calcutta',
    'components' => [`

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly are you trying to do.This is what your code is doing: In one iteration it calls some api, than it creates three records with current time +5min, +10min and +15min. There is no delay between the iterations so unless tha api call itself takes some time there is no reason why the times of next triplet should be different.

Comment: @mohsen The 'timeZone' is already set.

Comment: 60 time  call db and  curl to another host  and  3 time set time for every insert?

Answer (score 0):

customize this:

```
$dt = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo $dt . '<br>'; //now
$min5Later = strtotime('+5 minutes', strtotime($dt));//5 min later from $dt
$min5LaterFormat = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $min5Later);

$min10Later = strtotime('+10 minutes', strtotime($dt));//10 min later from $dt
$min10LaterFormat = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $min10Later);

$min15Later = strtotime('+15 minutes', strtotime($dt));//15 min later from $dt
$min15LaterFormat = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $min15Later);

for ($i = 0; $i <= 2; $i++) {
    $min5Later = strtotime('+5 minutes', strtotime($min5LaterFormat));//5 min later from $min5later
    $min5LaterFormat = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $min5Later);
    $min10Later = strtotime('+10 minutes', strtotime($min10LaterFormat));//10 min later from $min10later
    $min10LaterFormat = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $min10Later);
    $min15Later = strtotime('+15 minutes', strtotime($min15LaterFormat));//15 min later from $min15later
    $min15LaterFormat = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $min15Later);

 echo $min5LaterFormat . ' | ';
 echo $min10LaterFormat . ' | ';
 echo $min15LaterFormat . ' | <br>';
}
```

output:

```
2020-05-10 19:19:47
2020-05-10 19:29:47 | 2020-05-10 19:39:47 | 2020-05-10 19:49:47 |
2020-05-10 19:34:47 | 2020-05-10 19:49:47 | 2020-05-10 20:04:47 |
2020-05-10 19:39:47 | 2020-05-10 19:59:47 | 2020-05-10 20:19:47 |
```