# DateTime plus 1 month will return wrong date

Tags: php

I stumbled upon this today:

If I substract 1 month and 1 day from today's date I get 2020-10-31 and if I reverse this, so I add 1 month and 1 day back to the original date then I should get todays date, but I get tomorrows date instead.

```
$now=DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2020-12-01');
$now->sub(new DateInterval('P1M1D'));
$now->add(new DateInterval('P1M1D'));
echo($now->format('Y-m-d')); \\ prints 2020-12-02
assert($now->format('Y-m-d')=='2020-12-01'); \\Fails
```

Does anyone have an explanation for this and how could I avoid getting the wrong date back?

**Edit**

- The code itself is useless as it is. This issue was caught by one of my unit tests. The test is checking how many days are between the current date and a given date  minus `P1M1D`. This test got 1 instead of 0 yesterday.
- I tried to use different ways to get the day like `strtotime('-1 month -1 day')` and `DateTime`'s `modify` method

**Edit 2**

I actually found this exact issue on stackoverflow (have no idea how I didn't find it yesterday)[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3602421/5923584) answers my question in detail.

Comment: Don't subtract/add a day? Movements from the end of of the month is wonky due to the number of days each month. It's best to do it from the start of the month.

Comment: Why do you need to reverse it? You already have your original date.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: Please see edit.